# Swipe Action latency

Tags: swift, latency, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have added swipe action to my application. I have 5 buttons which represent days of the week. When I click on one button it changes the array of my table view and some things. 
Swipe action does exactly the same and works great but on swipe sometimes it freezes and works again after some seconds. it's latency.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(actionSwipeRight))
    rightSwipe.direction = .right

    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(actionSwipeLeft))
    leftSwipe.direction = .left

    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
}
```

And the swipe code

```
// s'éxécute lorsque qu'un swipe vers la droite est effectué
@objc private func actionSwipeRight() {
    print("swipe right")

    switch self.selectedDayinHoraire {
        case "LUNDI" :
            return
        case "MARDI" :
            changeDay(for: "LUNDI")
        case "MERCREDI" :
           changeDay(for: "MARDI")
        case "JEUDI" :
            changeDay(for: "MERCREDI")
        case "VENDREDI" :
            changeDay(for: "JEUDI")
        default: break
    }
}

// s'éxécute lorsque qu'un swipe vers la gauche est effectué
@objc private func actionSwipeLeft() {
    print("swipe left")

    switch self.selectedDayinHoraire {
        case "LUNDI" :
           changeDay(for: "MARDI")
        case "MARDI" :
           changeDay(for: "MERCREDI")
        case "MERCREDI" :
            changeDay(for: "JEUDI")
        case "JEUDI" :
            changeDay(for: "VENDREDI")
        case "VENDREDI" :
            return
        default: break
    }
}

func changeDay(for day : String) {
    switch day {
        case "LUNDI" :
                self.menuSelectionné(btn: self.btnLundi)
                self.LabelDynamiqueJour.text = " horaire du lundi"
                self.selectedDayinHoraire = "LUNDI"
        case "MARDI" :
                self.menuSelectionné(btn: self.btnMardi)
                self.LabelDynamiqueJour.text = " horaire du Mardi"
                self.selectedDayinHoraire = "MARDI"
        case "MERCREDI" :
                self.menuSelectionné(btn: self.btnMercredi)
                self.LabelDynamiqueJour.text = " horaire du Mercredi"
                self.selectedDayinHoraire = "MERCREDI"
        case "JEUDI" :
                self.menuSelectionné(btn: self.btnJeudi)
                self.LabelDynamiqueJour.text = " horaire du Jeudi"
                self.selectedDayinHoraire = "JEUDI"
        case "VENDREDI" :
                self.menuSelectionné(btn: self.btnVendredi)
                self.LabelDynamiqueJour.text = " horaire du vendredi"
                self.selectedDayinHoraire = "VENDREDI"
        default: break
    }
    tableviewHoraire.reloadData()
}
```

The buttons actions :

```
@IBAction func btnLun(_ sender: UIButton) {
    changeDay(for: "LUNDI")
}

@IBAction func btnMar(_ sender: UIButton) {
   changeDay(for: "MARDI")
}

@IBAction func btnMer(_ sender: UIButton) {
   changeDay(for: "MERCREDI")
}

@IBAction func btnJeu(_ sender: UIButton) {
   changeDay(for: "JEUDI")
}

@IBAction func btnVen(_ sender: UIButton) {
   changeDay(for: "VENDREDI")
}
```

You can see swipe action do the same but sometimes it freezes, test it yourself if you want, the problem comes from Horaire view. https://github.com/CedricLnx/School-Companion

Comment: are you testing on a simulator or real Device?

Comment: Réal device @Chameleon

Comment: i haven't fully tested it, but are you buttons in the same are as the swipe is taking place? if so I would guess the latency has to do with the system trying to decide if it's a touch on the button or a swipe gesture.

Comment: Ni there aren’t, I really suggest to test on real device to understand the problem

Comment: it requests a `username` and `password` to get past first scene.

Comment: No just press connexion it will work and swipe a lot of time in horaire view

Comment: i think i see what you mean. if user "rapidly" swipes, it doesn't fire?

Comment: Exactly ! That’s the problem

Comment: seems to be the tableView is intercepting the rapid swipes. if you  do rapid swipes where the tableView is not it works fine.

Comment: I think it’s not that, like you have seen it block many seconds before to be unlocked

Comment: i just tested it. rapid swipe on the "Lun-Mar-Mer-Jeu-Ven" section and you will see that the rapid swipes have no latency

Comment: Yes, you are right. How to fix it ?

Comment: is your user going to interact with the tableView, or only use it for viewing information?

Comment: User interact, enable when user select a cell yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your Horaire class as subclass of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

```
class Horaire: ViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
```

Set each Swipe's delegate to self.

```
    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(actionSwipeRight))
    rightSwipe.direction = .right
    rightSwipe.delegate = self

    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(actionSwipeLeft))
    leftSwipe.direction = .left
    leftSwipe.delegate = self
```

Add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate Function.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

As explained in [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624208-gesturerecognizer) shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith allows two or more gestures to work at the sametime. In this case it should allow a single touch to be registered as a swipe on self.view as well as on tableView.

Comment: thank you man, I setted Horaire as subclass of UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and settled delegate to self for each. 
The func fix my problem, can you explain me what that func exactly do ?

Comment: @CédricLoneux good to hear, I'll explain in my answer. And please accept answer if it solved your issue.